# Define rules for AllegroGraph triples and how to apply them

Tags: semantic-web, reasoning, allegrograph

I'm using AllegroGraph to store statement like this:

```
<newsid1  hasAnnotation  Gamma>
<newsid1  hasAnnotation Beta>
```

I would like to define a rule on this staments that says: *if the subject* `newsid1 hasAnnotation` *either* `Gamma` *or* `Beta`, *then add a new statement in the triplestore that says that the subject* `hasAnnotation Theta`, i.e. the statement

```
<newsid1  hasAnnotation Theta>
```

My questions are the following:

1. How I can define such a rule for Allegro?
2. How can I apply these rules over the statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You can define use [Prolog functors](http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/current/prolog-tutorial.html) to define these rules. In your case you will define.

```
;; Functors to add triples.
(<-- (a-- ?s ?p ?o)
;; Fails unless all parts ground.
(lispp (not (get-triple :s ?s :p ?p :o ?o)))
(lisp (add-triple ?s ?p ?o)))

;; Functors to seek news that should have theta annotation
(<-- (shouldHaveAnnotationTheta ?news)  
(q- ?news !namespace:hasAnnotation !"Gamma"))

(<- (shouldHaveAnnotationTheta ?news)  
(q- ?news !namespace:hasAnnotation !"Beta"))
```

2) Run then the following prolog query (using the AGview for exemple) to add these news statements

```
(select (?news)
(shouldHaveAnnotationTheta ?news)
(a-- ?news !namespace:hasAnnotation !"Theta")
(fail))
```

You can read the following documents to understand this code :

- [Prolog functors](http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/current/prolog-tutorial.html)
- [Lisp Reference](http://franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/v4/lisp-reference.html)

Comment: Hello, Aymeric! Thank you for your helpful answer. I would like to ask you if there is a programmatic way (saying by using Java language or script language) to execute such kind of rules over the AllegroGraph? I have a pipeline that poor statements into the AG and after the process is finished, rules should be applied. Thank you again. Regards, Florin

Comment: Well you can store all the functors server-side using the scripts or the initfile. You can after that run some queries to add the new statements using the AllegroGraph HTTP API.

Comment: I have stumbled on a similar problem. The thing is, I want to add a triple only if it doesn't already exist. From what I have read, your adding functor(a--) should do this. I have copied it, but it doesn't seem to work. The triple is added, no matter if it already exists or not. Why is this happening? I have posted the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095983/allegrograph-check-existing-triple)