# AllegroGraph check existing triple

Tags: prolog, allegrograph

I am using AllegroGraph 4. I have a triple store, and I am trying to add new triples only if they don't already exist.

Here is my Prolog query:

```
(select (?news) (alfas ?news) (a-- ?news !tst:has-annotation !tst:Test)))
```

where alfas checks for a condition(it works fine) and `a--` is defined like this:

```
(<-- (a-- ?s ?p ?o)
;; Fails unless all parts ground.
(lisp (not (triple-exists-p ?s ?p ?o)))
(lisp (add-triple ?s ?p ?o)))
```

I have also tried defining it like this:

```
(<-- (a-- ?s ?p ?o)
;; Fails unless all parts ground.
(lisp (not (get-triple :s ?s :p ?p :o ?o)))
(lisp (add-triple ?s ?p ?o)))
```

But the triple is added anyway, no matter if it already exists or not. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt is more correct, but you should use `lispp` instead of `lisp` to check if the triple already exists:

```
(<-- (a-- ?s ?p ?o)
;; Fails unless all parts ground.
(lispp (not (get-triple :s ?s :p ?p :o ?o)))
(lisp (add-triple ?s ?p ?o)))
```

You've seen this code already, because you commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924654/define-rules-for-allegrograph-triples-and-how-to-apply-them). But you must not have noticed the `lispp` functor, or understood that it runs as a predicate - as described in the [documentation](https://franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/prolog.html).